# Converting into Intel 64 assembly

Tags: assembly, intel

I have a snippet of code that I need to convert into commented Intel 64 assembly. I have given it a shot but I know that I have made some errors so I would appreciate if someone could point these errors out for me and tell me the correct way of doing it.

Code to be converted:

```
void test (int x)
{
    int y, z;
    y = 5;
    z = 2*y;
    x = z+x;
    if (z>0)
        z = -z;
    while (z<0) {
        y = y+y;
        z++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 8;
    test (x);
}
```

My attempt at conversion:

```
test:       pop rax; x variable from stack
            mov rbx 5; y variable
            mov rcx rbx; z variable
            imul rcx 2; z = z*y
            add rdx rcx; x = z+x

ifz:        cmp rcx 0; if statement
            jle whilez;
            imul rcx -1; z = -z

whilez:     cmp rcx 0; while statement
            jge endwhile;
            add rbx rbx; y=y+y
            add rcx 1; z++
            jmp whilez; loop back

endwhile:   

main:       mov rax 8; int x = 8
            push rax; push x onto stack for method call
            jmp test;
```

Comment: Your assembly syntax doesn't match any assembler I'm familiar with. Usually there are commas between arguments to the instructions. I'm not sure why you're using a jump for a function call. Normally, you would use a `call`. There's also a specific calling convention when doing calls in the C compatible world. A quick way to convert C to assembly is to run `gcc -S myfile.c` and then hand edit/optimize/beautify the associated `.s` file (which will be in AT&T format).

Comment: @lurker: If you dislike AT&T (which I love), you can pass `-masm=intel` to gcc.

Comment: @EOF why do you assume I dislike AT&T format? I said nothing about whether I like or dislike it. I was pointing out that AT&T format is what you get by default with `-S`. By "beatify" I meant to use perhaps more readable variable names, labels, etc. The OP appears to be leaning toward Intel format.

Comment: @lurker: Ah, I see. I hope you can nevertheless accept my comment in good faith, as a useful bit of knowledge for those who prefer intel-syntax (even though they are shouty barbarians).

Comment: @lurker yes that was something I am not quite understanding. How would I use call? Would call handle the variables as well? Thanks a lot

Comment: @EOF it was very good that you cited the `-masm=intel` option (+1), which I neglected. I sort of default to Intel format for some odd reason. Probably because it's what I "grew up on" when doing 8086 assembly. But either format works for me. :)

Comment: @KVohra95 you might want to read up on the basics x64 assembly language ([here](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2130-001/x64-intro.pdf) and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly) for example) before tackling this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What errors are you getting while compiling/linking this?

Right off the bat I notice you have some syntax errors. For Intel-Based assembly the syntax for mov's are...

```
mov rax, rbx     ; You forgot the comma
add rcx, 8       ; Just another example
```

This is also the case for the 'imul', 'add', and 'cmp' calls.

Also while not technically incorrect, you add semicolons to the end of lines. In Assembly semicolons are not necessary at the end and are instead the identifier for comments. The commas were the major issue I noticed. I would try to compile and link that and if it still doesn't work I can take another look.

Comment: I havent compiled this and I dont know how to test whether my code produces the same result. Thank you for the commas yes I forgot them. Basically this is an exercise to convert it on paper. I mainly had 2 questions: did I perform my method call correctly? I pushed the variable to the stack and then popped it, is this correct? Also do I need to perform some command on the end of the function being called to tell the computer it is the end of the function? Thanks

Comment: Oh okay. Yes you pushed and popped to the stack correctly. Instead of using 'jmp' I always use 'call' but this should not make a difference. And lastly in the 'endwhile' section you want to do the command 'ret' so that this is not an infinite loop/

Comment: Actually the use of `jmp` in this case will make a huge difference since the `test` function doesn't "return" and it falls right back into `main`. That's an issue. A `call` should be used with a suitable `ret` at the end of the `test` function.

Comment: I'm assuming the rest of the code makes sense then?

Comment: @KVohra95 not quite. For example, in `test`, you pop the variable `x` into `rax`, but then your instruction for `x = z + x` assumes that `x` is in `rdx`. There may be other issues, but I stopped reading through it due to it not being structured properly at all. I think it would be good if you looked at the links I provided and apply what you learn there. Then ask if you get stuck on a more specific point.